# How to drop printing "0.000*" values in my code but pass everything else through?

Tags: php

I am having some trouble coming up with meaningful all-cases covered boolean expression for this:

```
$vars = [
    "0.000",//do not print this value, as it is "not set"
    "0.00", //do not print
    0.00,   //do not print
    "TBD",  //print
    "14.5", //print
    14.5    //print
];

foreach ($vars as $var) {
    if (/* ... */)
        print "$var<br>\n";    //print only the "to be printed" values
}
```

For one, `$var != 0` fails.  `$var !== 0`, also fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this which takes all non numeric items and any value not equal to 0

```
if ($var != 0 || !is_numeric($var))
```

Comment: It works for me based of the items shown. Returns TBN, 14.5, 14.5

Comment: Correction: **it works**. Previously I checked with `if ($var || ! is_numeric($var))` and it displayed the first two strings too.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    if ((is_numeric($var) && floatVal($var) > 0) || (!is_numeric($var) && strlen($var) > 0)) {
        print "$var<br>\n";    //print only the "to be printed" values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
<?php
   $vars = [
    "0.000",//do not print this value, as it is "not set"
    "0.00", //do not print
    0.00,   //do not print
    "TBD",  //print
    "14.5", //print
    14.5    //print
];


$vars = array_filter($vars,function($a){ return !is_numeric($a) ? $a : (float)$a; });

var_dump($vars);
```

Comment: I like the `array_filter`, I may use that!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    if (!preg_match('/^0(\.?)(0*)/', $var, $match))
    print "$var<br>\n";    //print only the "to be printed" values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with something here ..

```
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    if (is_numeric($var) && $var != 0 || (is_string($var) && !is_numeric($var)))
        print "$var\n";
}
```

Comment: Problem with that is when a string is converted to the context of a number, it is always represented as integer zero. So `$var != 0` will not pass.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex of (0?.?0?)

```
if (!preg_match('/(0?.?0?)/',(string)$var))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_numeric($var) || int($var) != 0){

}
```